# JavaScript recursive function returning NaN

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, nan

The JavaScript function `nuovaX` below returns `NaN` if it is called for `s!=0`. How can I get rid of this?

```
function d(s,di,dd){
    var ris=di*Math.pow(dd,s);
    return ris;
}

function nuovaX(s,di,dd,angolo,xi){
    var x=0;
    if(s==0){
        x=xi;       
    }
    else{
        x=nuovaX(s-1,di,dd,angolo)+d(s,di,dd)*Math.cos(s*angolo);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle where we can test it.

Comment: At the very least, we need to see sample calls, along with their expected outcomes.

Comment: Obviously an unpopular opinion, but I don't agree with the down-votes - I can see why @Leonardo Mutti didn't feel the need to provide any extra information in this case. The function is returning NaN - that means some invalid mathematical operation was occurring, therefore no extra context is required.

Comment: @GershomMaes though we now know the cause, there are parameters passed to the function that *could* cause the error, but which aren't examined in the case when `s` is `0`. For example, if the function were called with the `angolo` parameter set to `"foo"` or `null`, the function would fail similarly. (Now, is that worth *four* downvotes? Probably not.)

Comment: I just assumed that the parameters weren't part of the problem - it seemed implicit. Maybe it would have been worthwhile to state that explicitly :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified it a little:

```
function d(s, di, dd){
    return di * Math.pow(dd, s);
}

function nuovaX(s, di, dd, angolo, xi){
    if(s==0) return xi;
    return nuovaX(s-1, di, dd, angolo) + d(s, di, dd) * Math.cos(s * angolo);
}
```

`nuovaX` expects 5 parameters, but its recursive call to itself only receives 4 parameters - missing `xi`.

Answer (score 1):

here is missing `xi`:

```
x=nuovaX(s-1,di,dd,angolo)+d(s,di,dd)*Math.cos(s*angolo);
                        /\
                        /\
```

so in second iteration `xi` is `undefined`.